# How to preselect nodes using jsTree jQuery plug-in

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jstree

I am using the jsTree jQuery plug-in with its "Checkbox" plug-in and using an async http request to lazy-load each level of the tree. All works great, except that I cannot get the tree to pre-select certain nodes after the first level. I am using the "selected" attribute to provide an array of ID's to preselect. ID's in the top level of the tree are correctly pre-selected. However, ID's in lower levels of the tree are not selected when the level loads. Am I missing something?

Here is the constructor code:

```
    var myArrayOfIDs = new Array();
    myArrayOfIDs[0] = '123';  //etc...

    $(sDivID).tree(
        {
            data : {
                async : true,
                opts : {url : sURL}
            },
            plugins:{ 
                "checkbox" : {three_state : false}
            },
            selected : myArrayOfIDs,
            ui:{
                theme_name : "checkbox",
                dots : false,
                animation : 400
            },
            callback : {
                beforedata : function(NODE, TREE_OBJ) { return { id : $(NODE).attr("id") || 0, rand : Math.random().toString() } }
            }
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, your code looks fine to me.

I took a slightly different approach in my solution because I wanted the server i.e. your sURL to tell me which items should be selected - then in jsTree's onload callback I select them.

Update: I've updated my jsTree blog post to the latest version of jsTree [here](http://mattfrear.com/2011/12/17/jstree-revisited/)

-Matt

Comment: As Matt Frear comment on his blog mattfrear.com/2010/05/19/jstree, this can't work anymore. So we don't have any other solution?

Comment: @Vinh I've updated my blog post so it now works with 1.0 version of jsTree.

Comment: Hi, I want to thank you @Matt Frear. I used your article and it helped me much. But now I want to make selected nodes onload. it does not work for me. Can you watch to my question about it, please?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17519593/how-to-make-some-selected-items-as-checked-on-load-in-jstree-selected-selec

Answer (score 6):

```
$(".jstree").jstree({
    "plugins" : [ "themes", "html_data", "checkbox", "ui" ],
    "checkbox": {
        "real_checkboxes": true,
        "real_checkboxes_names": function (n) {
            return [n[0].id, 1];
        },
        "two_state": true
    }
}).bind("loaded.jstree", function (event, data) {
    $('li[selected=true]').each(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('jstree-unchecked').addClass('jstree-checked');
    });
});
```

I'm using this for the latest version of jstree.

Comment: From my understanding, this will only handle the css and cause issues when the user deselects the node. I was able to preselect nodes using in this example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34877409/4896260)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I update selection after tree was loaded:

```
$('#jstree_div')
      .on('changed.jstree', treeChanged)
      .on('loaded.jstree', treeLoaded)
      .jstree({
      'plugins': ["checkbox"],
      'core': {
          'data': {
              'url': '/xmldata/getcategories'
          }
      }
  });

function treeLoaded(event, data) {
    data.instance.select_node(['2', '5']); //node ids that you want to check
}
```