# How to make some selected items as checked on load in jstree. (selected = "selected" not working)

Tags: javascript, jquery, tree, jstree, treemodel

In MVC 4 i use jstree. In create operation I have not problem. But in Edit operation, I set `true` value to some items of treemodel. models are like:

```
public class RecursiveObject
{             
    public string data { get; set; }
    public Int64 id { get; set; }  
    public FlatTreeAttribute attr { get; set; }
    public List<RecursiveObject> children { get; set; }
}

public class FlatTreeAttribute
{
    public string id;
    public bool selected;
}
```

When I fill tree model, i set `selected = true;` to some items and use this in view:

```
json_data: {
                "ajax": {
                    url: "@Url.Action("GetTreeData", "MyController")",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json charset=utf-8"
                }
            },
```

But in view, all items are unchecked. I see some `<li>` tags have `selected = "selected"`,  but this does not affect it's checking.

When I check item **manually**, `jstree-unchecked` changes to `jstree-checked` class. It means that `selected = "selected"` does not work.

[image]

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution for my question.

```
.bind("loaded.jstree", function (event, data) {
    $('li[selected=selected]').each(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('jstree-unchecked').addClass('jstree-checked');
    });
});
```