# How to load jstree checkbox on load VB ASP

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, jstree

I'm trying to load jstree checkboxes on load using ASP. The code behind takes a tree node and populates a list item for the jstree to use. In this process, there are nodes that are identified as "Checked", in which I add the class attribute *jstree-clicked* to the list item. However when the page loads, it doesn't have any effect. Please let me know what to the appropriate way to populate these check boxes with the check boxes pre-checked. I have the following in my back end

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim tNode As TreeNode
    Dim treeView As New TreeView
    Dim tNodeCollection As New TreeNodeCollection
    tNodeCollection = treeView.Nodes

    ' Code to generate and store within
    ' a System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView object
    ' ...
    ' ...
    ' ...

    repeater.DataSource = tNodeCollection 
    repeater.DataBind()
End Sub

Protected Sub repeater_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs)
    Dim tNode As TreeNode
    Dim li As New HtmlGenericControl
    Dim ul As New HtmlGenericControl("ul")
    tNode = e.Item.DataItem

    If (tNode Is Nothing) Then
        Return
    End If

    li = e.Item.FindControl("listItem")
    li.ID = tNode.Value
    li.InnerHtml = tNode.Text
    If tNode.Checked Then
        li.Attributes.Add("rel", "true")
    End If

    If tNode.ChildNodes.Count > 0 Then
        li.Controls.Add(ul)
        searchChildNodes(tNode.ChildNodes, ul)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub searchChildNodes(childNodes As TreeNodeCollection, ul As HtmlGenericControl)
    Dim tNode As TreeNode
    For Each tNode In childNodes
        Dim li As New HtmlGenericControl("li")
        li.ID = tNode.Value
        li.InnerHtml = tNode.Text
        ul.Controls.Add(li)
        If tNode.ChildNodes.Count > 0 Then
            Dim unorderedList As New HtmlGenericControl("ul")
            li.Controls.Add(unorderedList)
            searchChildNodes(tNode.ChildNodes, unorderedList)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Below is the aspx portion of the code.

```
<div id="myTreeNode" > 
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptr" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" OnItemDataBound="repeater_ItemDataBound" >
    <headerTemplate>
        <ul>
    </headerTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li id="listItem" runat="server"></li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </ul>
    </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the javascript file, the jsTree then checks for the attribute and preselects the check box once everything has been loaded. This appropriately selects the check box. As mentioned in the comment above, this avoids only handling the CSS but rather handles the entire node.

```
$("#myTreeNode").bind('ready.jstree', function (event, data) {
    var $tree = $(this);
    $($tree.jstree().get_json($tree, {
        flat: true
    })).each(function () {
    var checked = $(this).attr('rel');
    var node;
    if( checked == "true"){
        node = $("#myTreeNode").jstree().select_node(this.id);
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not the `li` element where you should add `jstree-clicked` class (I see it in this line: `li.Attributes.Add("class", "jstree-clicked")` ) but the `a` element inside that `li`.

Make sure you set that class for an immediate `a` child of the `li`.

Comment: Would I need to set the `a` element class via jQuery since the `a` element is added from the jsTree plugin? If so, what jsTree function would be appropriate to call?

Comment: Just add class to `a` element, jsTree will take care of css. But I see a problem - this will only visualize the checked nodes but won't work correctly if a user tries to uncheck these nodes. To enable a user to do this I see two options: either 1) set configuration of the tree (e.g. in JSON) and then feed it to jsTree upon its initialization; there just set `"state":{"selected":true}` for nodes you want preselected; or 2) access nodes after jsTree initialization and select them with `$("#yourtreeid").jstree().select_node` method. Check: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/7fp4hc8o/)